# Request Timeout: GET request timesout when retrieving a file

Tags: node.js, http

I need to display a PDF file uploaded to a different server in my application. I used an `iframe` tag with the src attribute pointed to the needed URL.

I also want to allow the user to print the said PDF file but I can't due to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

So, I decided to instead carry out a GET request from within my server to the other server that has the PDF file - the idea being that I fetch the PDF from the other server into my server and then replace the `src` attribute of the `iframe` tag with a route that my server handles and responds with the PDF file, if that makes sense

My GET request looks like:

```
var options = {
    host: host, //the hostname of the server that contains the PDF
    path: path, //the path on the other server that responds with the PDF
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {}
};

http.request(options, function (response) {
    var body = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("Gettin data");
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        var data = null;
        if (body) {
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            catch (err) {
                data = body;
            }
        }

        res.sendfile(data);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the request simply times out. Should I be setting some headers? The URL works fine when I directly place it in the address bar of the browser - that is the PDF file is displayed...

Comment: Figured it out. I was not calling `request.end()` after invoking the http request...

Comment: either answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation which can be found [here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), I needed to end the request.

Thus adding the following solved the issue:

```
var request = http.request(...);

request.end();
```

This ended the request and I no longer got a timeout.